# Looping through an array to display images with Nivo-Slider jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I have asked a similar question before but I was not completing clear in my aims so I am asking again with more information.
I am trying to write a script that uses "jquery.nivo.slider.js" to create a slide show of images on a page. I have read all the post on the subject of nivo-slider but none deal with using variables returned from a query.

The image names are stored in a MySQL data table along with the animation speed and the pause time.
I run the query to get the data and then pass the returned variable to the nivo-slider script.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var TimeLapse = '<?php echo $row_fb['TimeLapse'];?>';   
    var Effect = '<?php echo $row_fb['Effect'];?>'; 
    var AnimSpeed = '<?php echo $row_fb['AnimSpeed'];?>';
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: Effect,
        slices: 1,
        boxCols: 1,
        boxRows : 1,    
        animSpeed: AnimSpeed,
        pauseTime: TimeLapse,
        startSlide: 0,
        directionNav: false,
        controlNav: false,
        controlNavThumbs: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        manualAdvance: false,
        prevText: '',
        nextText: '',
        randomStart: false,
        beforeChange: function(){},
        slideshowEnd: function(){},
        lastSlide: function(){},
        afterLoad: function(){},
        afterChange: function(){},
    });
});
```

To loop through the returned data I am using a php "do while" loop thinking that each record found would make use of the returned variables in the
nivo-slider script. The issue I have is the nivo-script is not picking up the "effect, animation and pause times but displays a random sequence
of the effect, animation and pause time.. The complete script looks like this:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="slider-wrapper">
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"> 
<?php do { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    var TimeLapse = '<?php echo $row_fb['TimeLapse'];?>';   
    var Effect = '<?php echo $row_fb['Effect'];?>'; 
    var AnimSpeed = '<?php echo $row_fb['AnimSpeed'];?>';
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: Effect,
        slices: 1,
        boxCols: 1,
        boxRows : 1,    
        animSpeed: AnimSpeed,
        pauseTime: TimeLapse,
        startSlide: 0,
        directionNav: false,
        controlNav: false,
        controlNavThumbs: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        manualAdvance: false,
        prevText: '',
        nextText: '',
        randomStart: false,
        beforeChange: function(){},
        slideshowEnd: function(){},
        lastSlide: function(){},
        afterLoad: function(){},
        afterChange: function(){},
    });
});
</script>
<img src="<?php echo $ImagePath.''.$row_fb['ImageName'];?>"   data-transition="<?php echo $row_fb['Effect'];?>" />
<?php } while($row_fb = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fb)); ?>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `TimeLapse` and `AnimSpeed ` should be numbers not strings and would be set only once per slider instance. As for your loop it doesn't make sense initializing the slider plugin more than once. If you are hoping for different speed/time for each slide that does not appear to be configurable without modifying the plugin itself

Comment: Side note: the `.load()` shortcut method for load event is deprecated as per jQuery api docs

Comment: @ charlietfl  Hi, the TimeLapse and AnimSpeed are numbers stored in the data table. With regard to the slider plugin what I was trying to do is set the Effect, TimeLapse and AnimSpeed for each image because I thought each side could have it's own animation settings. I have changed the .load to $(window).on('load'), (function()

Comment: You are quoting those numbers turning them into JS strings. Briefly scanning the source code it does not appear that individual image settings are a feature. Docs for that slider are not very good. If you need individual settings I'm sure you can find a different script/plugin for that

Comment: @ charlietfl Hi again, didn't spot the quotes, now removed but I still have the same issue. Do you know if it's possible to have different effects and times using nivo-slider, if so how would I go about assigning them to each slide?

Comment: As I mentioned above that plugin does not appear to have that level of configuration. The source code appears to use a single setting per slide for each of those properties. You can provide comma separated effect values  that will be used in random order though

Comment: @ charlietfl  Looks like I am barking up the wrong tree. Many thanks for your time. I will need to come up with another solutions. Keep safe.